# Make checklist only allow one checked box at a time

Tags: jquery

I have a list of inputs:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500' value='182,500'> Below QAR 182,500 
<input type='checkbox' name='182,500plus' value='182,500plus'> Above QAR 182,500 – Below QAR 365,000
<input type='checkbox' name='365,000' value='365,000'> Above QAR 365,000

<span class="custom-link btn border-width-0 info-submit btn-color-xsdn btn- outline btn-icon-left">Submit</span>
```

I want to restrict it to one checked box at a time. I tried doing so using this:

```
if ($("[name='182,500']").prop('checked')) {

$("[name='182,500plus']").prop('checked', false);
$("[name='365,000']").prop('checked', false);

} else if ($("[name='182,500plus']").prop('checked')) {

$("[name='182,500']").prop('checked', false);
$("[name='365,000']").prop('checked', false);

} else if ($("[name='365,000']").prop('checked')) {

$("[name='182,500']").prop('checked', false);
$("[name='182,500plus']").prop('checked', false);

}
```

but for some reason it's not working, any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: If you want to restrict the user to making only one choice, you should use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes. This works two ways: it is clear for the user and the desired behavior is build in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have an issue in event, you need to use on change event to trigger any code you want. Also you can improve your code to be like this:

```js
$('.chTrigger').on('change', function(){
 $('.chTrigger').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' class="chTrigger" name='182,500' value='182,500'> Below QAR 182,500 
<input type='checkbox' class="chTrigger" name='182,500plus' value='182,500plus'> Above QAR 182,500 – Below QAR 365,000
<input type='checkbox' class="chTrigger" name='365,000' value='365,000'> Above QAR 365,000

<span class="custom-link btn border-width-0 info-submit btn-color-xsdn btn- outline btn-icon-left">Submit</span>
```

Note: @Hans Dash comment is nice if you want a radio behavior. 
@Hans Dash Say:

> If you want to restrict the user to making only one choice, you should use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes. This works two ways: it is clear for the user and the desired behavior is build in